# Space consumed by ALTER command in Postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, alter-table, alter

Problem statement : in a postgresql table I am getting an error as "Integer out of range" for the column 'id' type 'serial integer'

RCA : As it is a serial integer column which already exceeded its maximum range of 2147483647. And it is unable to load more data

Solution : Need to change the datatype of the column from INTEGER to BIGINT.

for this solution I tried to execute the ALTER command ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id TYPE BIGINT But the table consists of more than 2 billion data. Due to which DB space got full during the execution of the ALTER COMMAND, and the execution was stopped in between.
Now I am not able to find where the space got utilized (500GB).

**Question: How/Where To clear the space consumed during execution of the ALTER command in DB user**

Comment: This question is more suitable for dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The ALTER TABLE needs to copy the table to make a new one with more space for the bigint.  Near the end of this process, both the old table and the new table (and all of their indexes) will transiently exist at the same time.  If there is not enough space to accommodate this, then you will generally get an error, the transaction will roll back, and the incomplete new table and indexes will automatically get cleaned up.  If you only look at disk usage after the error has already occurred, then you won't see the space being used, as it has already been cleaned up.

Based on your comment, it sounds like you suffered not just a regular error, but rather a crash.  You can get crashes if you run out of space on pg_wal at just the wrong time.  (It is usually best to have pg_wal on a different partition than the rest of the data directory, that way ordinary out of space conditions on the data directory don't turn into crashes.)

Is PostgreSQL running, just now low on space?  Or can't you get it up and running again at all?

Comment: Hi @jjanes, Thanks for the response. 
The ALTER TABLE command has aborted due to insufficient space. But after the abort the space is not cleaned up yet and we are not able to find where the actual space is consumed during this execution. Its consumed 500GB of disk space